# Jackson - BeanDeserializerBase

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to add a specific functionality to Jackson.

I want Jackson to be able to deserialize Objects without asking for the required type. I mean that i want to be able to serialize a class and append a "@class" property that will hold the class name to be used when deserializing.

I was able to append the class property without any problem building a custom `BeanSerializerBase` but I can not find any way to build my `BeanDeserializerBase` and make it work. I can not find any function that will let me extract the "@class" field and remove it from the `JsonParser` that need to be passed to a default deserializer that will let me decide the output class.

```
@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    while(!p.isClosed())
    {
        JsonToken t = p.nextToken();

        if(t.name() == "@class")
        {
            String cls = t.asString();

            try
            {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(cls);

                // remove @class field & default deserialize.
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me? as I'm really stuck! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `BeanDeserializerBase` you can turn on the Jackson's [global default typing](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) that would work for all the classes. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonTypeInfo {
    public static class Bean {
        public final String key;

        @JsonCreator
        public Bean(@JsonProperty("key") final String key) {this.key = key;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(
                        ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
                        "@class");
        final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Bean("value"));
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"@class":"stackoverflow.JacksonTypeInfo$Bean","key":"value"}
stackoverflow.JacksonTypeInfo$Bean@271053e1
```